# Authoring a plugin function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hey dudes, I have the following function:

```
$.fn.slideOut = function(speed,dir) { 
        this.animate({
            dir: '-1000px'
        }, speed);
    };
```

But the direction (`dir`) isn't being carried over and isn't giving me an error either.

I'm calling it like so:
`$('#element').slideOut(500,'top');`

So my quesiton = why is it not animating? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a variable property name, you cannot use object literals. You first have to create the object and then set the property with the "array access" syntax:

```
$.fn.slideOut = function(speed,dir) {
    var options = {};
    options[dir] = '-1000px';
    this.animate(options, speed);
};
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you - that makes a lot of sense actually +1 for you - will accept in 11 minutes :D

Comment: Oh, I don't know, you were a full 11 seconds ahead of me. ;-)

Comment: @both - well, i've voted up @T.J and I'm accepting @Felix because fair is fair : )

Answer (score 5):

You can't use a variable on the left-hand (name) side of an object literal property initializer, what you have there is actually the property name "dir". You'll have to do it like this:

```
$.fn.slideOut = function(speed,dir) { 
    var opts = {};
    opts[dir] = '-1000px';
    this.animate(opts, speed);
};
```

A bit off-topic, but probably worth pointing out that that plug-in function won't chain. Unless you have a good reason not to, return `this` for chainability (in this case, you can just return what `animate` returns, since `animate` returns `this`):

```
$.fn.slideOut = function(speed,dir) { 
    var opts = {};
    opts[dir] = '-1000px';
    return this.animate(opts, speed);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling

```
this.animate({
  dir: '-1000px'
}
```

in your plugin. It is normal that it doesn't use the one received as a parameter.

Comment: So you are confirming that his code does not work, but don't provide a solution?